# Spring LDAP transactional manager

Tags: java, spring, spring-ldap

I have a confusing scenario regarding transaction rollbacks with Spring.

I am successfully creating a new user, adding it to a group and assigning a role, however when I try to test the transaction rollback for exceptions such as "User already exists" I run into my issues.

So, when I try to create an existing user Spring triggers an exception and a rollback operation is started but, nothing happens and the user remains in the user list.

My question is, should I create the method for rollback, or should spring handle this on my behalf.

I have spent a good amount of time in the docs but am struggling as I'm a bit of a Spring / LDAP newbie

Thanks in advance

Ian

Comment: Are you using Spring LDAP?  If so, did you configure the transaction manager as in the [reference documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring-ldap/site/reference/html/transactions.html)?

Comment: Hi matts, yes I read the manual :-) but thanks for the link, its always a fair shout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

P.I.C.N.I.C - It was a config file issue in the end.. d'oh!!

http://www.usewisdom.com/fun/computer.html

Answer (score 0):

So you try to add a user that already exists.

This fails, of course.

Spring LDAP then tries to rollback all that happened before. Since the user creation is the first step of your transaction, I don't get what you expect to be rolled back.

Did I misunderstand something?

Comment: Hi Samuel, The rollback works as expected now, there was an typo in one of the config files.. thanks for taking the time to interact with this question